# How to sum $nC^{n-1}$ from 0 to infinity?

Tags: summation

Where C is a const. e.g. sum $n(.5)^{n-1}$, **OR** sum $n(2)^{n-1}$ from 0 to infinity. Thank you.

Comment: See [this similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn) for ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differentiate both sides of $\displaystyle\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n.$

In general, if we have a function $f(x)$ which is given by a power series $f(x) =\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ with radius of convergence $R$ then $f$ is differentiable, and $f'(x) =\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)a_{n+1} x^{n}.$ This is because for every $R>\epsilon>0,$  the Weierstrass M-test gives that $\displaystyle f_m(x) = \sum_{n=0}^m a_n x^n$ converges uniformly to $f(x)$ on $[-R+\epsilon, R-\epsilon].$ If $g_n \to g$ uniformly on $[a,b]$ and $g'_n \to h$ on $[a,b]$ then $g$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $g'=h$ (this is a basic theorem in real analysis) so we have justified why we can differentiate power series term by term.

Comment: Why the sum on the right from 0 to infinity could be diff.?

Comment: @RHS See my edited answer.